# calculate the date diff between the minimum in the same column depending on another column's condition using Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
d = {'country': ['US', 'US', 'US','US', 'US', 'US', 'UK', 'UK','UK','UK','UK'], 
     'status': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1,1,0, 0,  0, 1,1],
     'count':[0, 1, 10, 20,30,40,0,1,2,4,6],
     'date':['2020-04-05', '2020-04-06', '2020-04-07', '2020-04-11', '2020-04-12', 
             '2020-04-13', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', '2020-04-05', '2020-04-06', '2020-04-07']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The first thing I thought is to use

```
df['day_diff']=df.groupby(['country', 'status'])['date'].apply(lambda x: x - x.min())
```

However, the 0 days for US status0 should appear on 2020-04-06 rather than 2020-04-05, in which the count is 0 (sorry I don't know how to put the output properly here). So there should be two conditions for the group applied to the returned day_diff

1. count>0
2. date - date.min()

   ```
   country status  count   date    day_diff
       US  0   0   2020-04-05  0 days
   US  0   1   2020-04-06  1 days
   US  0   10  2020-04-07  2 days
   ```

   3   US  0   20  2020-04-11  6 days
   4   US  1   30  2020-04-12  0 days
   5   US  1   40  2020-04-13  1 days
   6   UK  0   0   2020-04-02  0 days
   7   UK  0   1   2020-04-03  1 days
   8   UK  0   2   2020-04-05  3 days
   9   UK  1   4   2020-04-06  0 days
   10  UK  1   6   2020-04-07  1 days

I hope to get a result similar to this (of course it does not work):

```
df.groupby(['country', 'status'])['date'].apply(lambda x: x - x.min() if df['count']>0)
```

To calculate the difference between the date and the earliest date in the group, depending on whether the count of the first date is above 0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include the error you're getting and what your expected output is?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. Hoping it will make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform()` to extract the min date:

```
min_dates = (df.date.mask(df['count'].eq(0))
               .groupby([df['country'],df['status']])
               .transform('min')
            )

df['date_diff'] = df['date'] - min_dates
```

Output:

```
   country  status  count       date date_diff
0       US       0      0 2020-04-05   -1 days
1       US       0      1 2020-04-06    0 days
2       US       0     10 2020-04-07    1 days
3       US       0     20 2020-04-11    5 days
4       US       1     30 2020-04-12    0 days
5       US       1     40 2020-04-13    1 days
6       UK       0      0 2020-04-02   -1 days
7       UK       0      1 2020-04-03    0 days
8       UK       0      2 2020-04-05    2 days
9       UK       1      4 2020-04-06    0 days
10      UK       1      6 2020-04-07    1 days
```

Comment: Thank you Quang, however, the question is still there: the first day should be defined the count>0. There should be another condition applied to that as the first day (0 days)